# Auto Updater questions can't use a utility

Tags: ms-access

I found this code that will auto update the front end of a database. I am having issues getting to actually work for me.

I use a table called AppConstants on the server's backend that has two columns: ConstantTitle and ConstantValue. One of the rows has ConstantTitle set to "AppVersion" and ConstantValue set to the version number.

Then I have a field with visibility set to False on my main form called VersionNo, and I set this field's value to ="VersionNumber" (where VersionNumber is the actual version number, e.g. ="1.25"). On the Main Form's OnLoad event, I have a macro that runs a DLookup in an IF command:

```
if DLookUp("[ConstantValue]", "tblAdmin", "[ConstantTitle] ='AppVersion'")    <>[Forms]![frmMain]![VersionNo] Then RunCode OpenUpdater()
Quit Access
End If
```

The code for OpenUpdater:

```
Code:
Function OpenUpdater()  'This sets the name of the code to call later
Dim accapp As Access.Application
Set accapp = New Access.Application
accapp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\$Data\MyUpdater.accde")  'Starts up   this   file
accapp.Visible = True
End Function
```

What it's doing: The macro checks the value of the VersionNumber in the table on the server. When I update the app copy on the server, I set a new version number in here and set my app copy's VersionNo field to the same number. When you're running the old version, your app sees that the version numbers don't match, and then it executes the Macro's 'Then' commands: it runs the OpenUpdater code and shuts itself off.

The OpenUpdater code simply starts the MyUpdater.accde program, which is by default installed on the user's PC along with the application itself. The OpenUpdater program executes the following code:

```
Code:
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo

'Copy the new version to the C drive
Dim SourceFile, DestinationFile As String
SourceFile = "Z:\Server\MyProgram.accde"   'Where to get the fresh copy
DestinationFile = "C:\$Data\MyProgram.accde"   'Where to put it
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
.copyfile SourceFile, DestinationFile, True     'This line does the  acual  copy and paste
End With

'Reopen MyProgram
Dim accapp As Access.Application
Set accapp = New Access.Application
accapp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\$Data\MyProgram.accde")
accapp.Visible = True
End Function
```

This Function is called in a Macro within MyUpdater, and the command just after the RunCode in this Macro is QuitAccess, which shuts off the Updater.

So my main program, when you open the main form, checks the version number on the server. If they're different, the main program starts the updater and then shuts itself down. The updater copies the fresh version off the server and pastes it in the correct place on the C drive, then starts up the program and shuts itself down.

From the end-user's perspective, the program starts, immediately quits, and then starts again a second or so later and now it's updated. It works awesome.

I followed all of the directions, when I run it a .laccdb pops up. Can anyone provide clarity on why this is happening?

Here is what I put in (In two separate modules)
    Option Compare Database

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo

'Copy the new version to the C drive
Dim SourceFile, DestinationFile As String
SourceFile = "C:\Users\Tyrone\Desktop\MasterDatabase.accdb"   'Where to get  the fresh copy
DestinationFile = "C:\Users\Tyrone\Desktop\copy.accdb"   'Where to put it
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
.CopyFile SourceFile, DestinationFile, True    'This line does the acual    copy and paste
End With

'Reopen MyProgram
Dim accapp As Access.Application
Set accapp = New Access.Application
accapp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\Users\Tyrone\Desktop\copy.accdb")
accapp.Visible = True
End Function



Function OpenUpdater()  'This sets the name of the code to call later
Dim accapp As Access.Application
Set accapp = New Access.Application
accapp.OpenCurrentDatabase  ("C:\Users\Tyrone\Desktop\MyUpdater.accde")  'Starts up this file
accapp.Visible = True
End Function
```

Comment: I used code like this and never noticed an laccdb 'pop up'. What exactly do you mean by 'pops up'? Code worked great for several years until IT updated computers and no longer allows programmatic copying of files. Very annoying.

Comment: @June7 Instead of the copy database being updated to match the mastercopy, a locked version of the copy database pops up on my laptop. Would you happen to have what you were using ?

Comment: I would recommend a different tool, try this one: http://www.peterssoftware.com/aps.htm

Comment: An laccdb file is a temporary file created by Access when an accdb file is open. It should not 'pop up'. Shouldn't even be aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, since you asked, here is my setup. Master development frontend file sits in a folder only I (as developer/administrator) has permissions for. New versions are copied to folder named Install where users download from. A Login form is bound to table Updates which has a single record and a textbox is bound to the Version field. I use a label on form for Version Number for comparison with field data.

```
Version
Ver 9.8.0
```

Code (which no longer works because IT computer update does not allow programmatic copying files) uses Windows Shell to open the db:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

'Check for updates to the program on start up - if values don't match then there is a later version
If Me.tbxVersion <> Me.lblVersion.Caption Then
    'because administrator opens the master development copy, only run this for non-administrator users
    If DLookup("Permissions", "Users", "UserNetworkID='" & Environ("UserName") & "'") <> "admin" Then
        'copy Access file
        CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CopyFile _
            gstrBasePath & "Program\Install\MaterialsDatabase.accdb", "c:\", True
        'allow enough time for file to completely copy before opening
        Dim Start As Double
        Start = Timer
        While Timer < Start + 3
            DoEvents
        Wend
        'load new version - SysCmd function gets the Access executable file path
        'Shell function requires literal quote marks in the target filename string argument, apostrophe delimiters fail, hence the quadrupled quote marks
        Shell SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir) & "MSAccess.exe " & """" & CurrentProject.FullName & """", vbNormalFocus
        'close current file
        DoCmd.Quit
    End If
Else
    'tbxVersion available only to administrator to update version number in Updates table
    'don't forget to edit the VersionNumber label before copying frontend to Install folder 
    Me.tbxVersion.Visible = False
    Call UserLogin
End If

End Sub

Private Sub tbxUser_AfterUpdate()
If Me.tbxUser Like "[A-z][A-z][A-z]" Or Me.tbxUser Like "[A-z][A-z]" Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Users(UserNetworkID, UserInitials, Permissions) VALUES('" & VBA.Environ("UserName") & "', '" & UCase(Me.tbxUser) & "', 'staff')"
    Call UserLogin
Else
    MsgBox "Not an appropriate entry.", vbApplicationModal, "EntryError"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserLogin()
Me.tbxUser = DLookup("UserInitials", "Users", "UserNetworkID='" & Environ("UserName") & "'")
If Not IsNull(Me.tbxUser) Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Users SET ComputerName='" & VBA.Environ("ComputerName") & "' WHERE UserInitials='" & Me.tbxUser & "'"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu", acNormal, , "UserInitials='" & Me.tbxUser & "'", , acWindowNormal
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That lock file appears when the DB is open and should disappear when the DB is closed. This has nothing to do with the copy operation. To ensure the copy is working, put a different file in there with the same name and watch the "update" happen.

Comment: Yeah I am realizing that. Both databases are on my desktop and I see the lock file appearing and disappearing when the code is being ran. I do not think the copy and paste part is working because The version number field would change to match the master copy